Can't install from source, even with RTools
Another installing from source installation challenge! I didn't see my specific issue mentioned in other similar questions, so posting here.
Problem: Installing packages from source fails on R4.2.3 Windows with RTools 4.2

With the units package, I tried install.packages('units',type = "source") and got the error pasted further below, ending in 'ERROR: compilation failed for package 'units'`
With terra, I tried the latest dev version (1.8-0) with install.packages('terra', repos='https://rspatial.r-universe.dev') and installing a somewhat older version (1.7-78) from the Posit package manager via Renv. The specific errors were different, but similarly ended with compilation failed.

Things I tried:

I did reinstall RTools 4.2 (latest version) after deleting out the old folder. For terra, I also updated GDAL using the installer at OSGeo4W, though I believe RTools uses its own version of GDAL.
I could install binaries or jump to newer R verison, but for various reasons need source compilation on 4.2.3 to work.

Settings:

R profile just has : options(error = NULL)
R environ has some passwords and API keys, nothing that modifies path
The first two items in sys.getenv("PATH") are C:\\rtools42\\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\\bin;C:\\rtools42\\usr\\bin;, so it seems that's there.
I also have a Windows environment variable set to RTOOLS42_HOME C:\rtools42 .
Sys.which("make") returns "C:\rtools42\usr\bin\make.exe"
system("gcc -v") returns the following

Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=C:\rtools42\X86_64~1.POS\bin\gcc.exe
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/rtools42/x86_64~1.pos/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/10.4.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix
Configured with: /root/mxe/tmp-gcc-host-x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/gcc-10.4.0/configure --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr/lib/mxe/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix --with-native-system-header-dir=/usr/lib/mxe/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,fortran --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-gcc --with-gnu-ld --with-gnu-as --disable-nls --without-libiconv-prefix --disable-shared --disable-multilib --without-x --disable-win32-registry --enable-threads=posix --enable-libgomp --with-gmp=/usr/lib/mxe/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix --with-isl=/usr/lib/mxe/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix --with-mpc=/usr/lib/mxe/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix --with-mpfr=/usr/lib/mxe/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix --enable-libstdcxx-time target_configargs=XCFLAGS=-Wno-format
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 10.4.0 (GCC) 

Details: Here's the error for install.packages('units',type = "source") --terra has a much longer (and different) set of errors:
* installing *source* package 'units' ...
** package 'units' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation

  **********************************************
  WARNING: this package has a configure script
        It probably needs manual configuration
  **********************************************


** libs
rm -Rf units.dll RcppExports.o udunits.o
g++ -std=gnu++14  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.3/include" -DNDEBUG -DUDUNITS2_DIR=0 -I'C:/Users/OPname/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2/Rcpp/include'   -I"C:\Users\OPname\AppData\Local/R/cache/R/renv/extsoft/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
g++ -std=gnu++14  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.3/include" -DNDEBUG -DUDUNITS2_DIR=0 -I'C:/Users/OPname/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2/Rcpp/include'   -I"C:\Users\OPname\AppData\Local/R/cache/R/renv/extsoft/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c udunits.cpp -o udunits.o
g++ -std=gnu++14 -shared -s -static-libgcc -o units.dll tmp.def RcppExports.o udunits.o -ludunits2 -lexpat -LC:\Users\OPname\AppData\Local/R/cache/R/renv/extsoft/lib/x64 -LC:\Users\OPname\AppData\Local/R/cache/R/renv/extsoft/lib -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.3/bin/x64 -lR
C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\OPname\AppData\Local/R/cache/R/renv/extsoft/lib/x64/libudunits2.a(parser.o):parser.c:(.text+0x14a): undefined reference to `__imp___iob_func'
C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\OPname\AppData\Local/R/cache/R/renv/extsoft/lib/x64/libudunits2.a(parser.o):parser.c:(.text+0x1fb): undefined reference to `__imp___iob_func'
C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\OPname\AppData\Local/R/cache/R/renv/extsoft/lib/x64/libudunits2.a(parser.o):parser.c:(.text+0x343): undefined reference to `__imp___iob_func'
C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\OPname\AppData\Local/R/cache/R/renv/extsoft/lib/x64/libudunits2.a(parser.o):parser.c:(.text+0x97e): undefined reference to `__imp___iob_func'
C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\OPname\AppData\Local/R/cache/R/renv/extsoft/lib/x64/libudunits2.a(parser.o):parser.c:(.text+0xb0c): undefined reference to `__imp___iob_func'
C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\OPname\AppData\Local/R/cache/R/renv/extsoft/lib/x64/libudunits2.a(parser.o):parser.c:(.text+0x1060): more undefined references to `__imp___iob_func' follow
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
no DLL was created
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'units'
* removing 'C:/Users/OPname/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2/units'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/OPname/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2/units'
Warning in install.packages :
 installation of package ‘units’ had non-zero exit status

Big thank you to all!

"It probably needs manual configuration" seems like a good indication to look for documentation. The units package webpage has some special instructions for installing from source. Scroll to the bottom of the page and start reading at "Alternatively, install it from sources..."

So, my understanding is that basically every R package that imports Rcpp will have something message like this. What I'm trying to sort out with this question is less the specifics of udunits, but more that any package installed from source is failing consistently (such as terra, also mentioned).

A good way to install from source on Windows is to clone the package repo, navigate to one folder below it and run, on the command line (and with R on your path),
R CMD INSTALL terra

That should work for R 3.6 and up.
On Windows, install.packages('terra', repos='https://rspatial.r-universe.dev') installs a binary version of the development version if you use a more recent version of R.
All external libraries used come with RTools, so OSGeo4W won't change anything. On linux like systems having multiple GDAL/PROJ libraries installed can lead to problems.

Since none of this works, I now think that the underlying problem is that the configuration file for Windows and RTools4.4, Makevars.ucrt, is not compatible with RTools4.2. To install from source perhaps you can try
url <- "https://rspatial.r-universe.dev/bin/windows/contrib/4.4/terra_1.8-0.zip"
zip <- basename(url)
download.file(url, zip, mode="wb")

And then install from local source

Sadly, didn't do the trick, but thanks for the pointers and tips! Same compiliation errors mentioned above. In general, also looking for a solution that will address the underlying problem so I can use renv and not need to clone repositories to install source packages.

please see my expanded answer

Hmm, I'm still striking out. I used your install suggestions with R 4.4 and got an error (too long to post, but * installing *binary* package 'terra' ... cp: unknown option -- ). To be clear, i'm trying to install with R 4.2.3, but this issue with installing from source also appears with R 4.4.1 and RTools4.4 with the same issue for udunits.
